# html_entity_decode in specific regular expression for a preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, decode, html-entities, bbcode

I have this preg_replace patterns and replacements :

```
$patterns = array(
    "/<br\W*?\/>/",
    "/<strong>/",
    "/<*\/strong>/",
    "/<h1>/",
    "/<*\/h1>/",
    "/<h2>/",
    "/<*\/h2>/",
    "/<em>/",
    "/<*\/em>/",
    '/(?:\<code*\>([^\<]*)\<\/code\>)/',
);
$replacements = array(
    "\n",
    "[b]",
    "[/b]",
    "[h1]",
    "[/h1]",
    "[h2]",
    "[/h2]",
    "[i]",
    "[/i]",
    '[code]***HTML DECODE HERE***[/code]',
);
```

In my string I want to `html_entity_decode` the content between these tags :
 `<code> &lt; $gt; </code>` but keep my array structure for preg replace

so this : `<code> &lt; &gt; </code>` will be this : `[code] < > [/code]`

Any help will be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot encode this in the replacement string. As PoloRM suggested, you could use `preg_replace_callback` specifically for your last replacement instead:

```
function decode_html($matches)
{
    return '[code]'.html_entity_decode($matches[1]).'[/code]';
}

$str = '<code> &lt; &gt; </code>';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?:\<code*\>([^\<]*)\<\/code\>)/', 'decode_html', $str);
```

Equivalently, using `create_function`:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?:\<code*\>([^\<]*)\<\/code\>)/',
    create_function(
       '$matches',
        'return \'[code]\'.html_entity_decode($matches[1]).\'[/code]\';'
    ),
    $str
);
```

Or, as of PHP 5.3.0:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(?:\<code*\>([^\<]*)\<\/code\>)/',
    function ($matches) {
        return '[code]'.html_entity_decode($matches[1]).'[/code]';
    },
    $str
);
```

But note that in all three cases, your pattern is not really optimal. Firstly, you don't need to escape those `<` and `>` (but that is just for readability). Secondly, your first `*` allows infinite repetition (or omission) of the letter `e`. I suppose you wanted to allow attributes. Thirdly, you cannot include other tags within your `<code>` (because `[^<]` will not match them).  In this case maybe you should go with ungreedy repetition instead (I also changed the delimiter for convenience):

```
~(?:<code[^>]*>(.*?)</code>)~
```

As you can already see, this is still far from perfect (in terms of correctly matching the HTML in the first place). Hence, the obligatory reminder: [don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You will be much better off, using a DOM parser. PHP brings a [built-in one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), and there is also [this very convenient-to-use 3rd-party one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think I'll consider the DOM Parser but it's a bit more complicated :p

Comment: @user990463, especially with the second one I linked it is really not all that complicated. It's very easy to use (just go to their documentation and check out some of the examples).

Comment: Yes I wish to use this one but for technical issues (not depending on me) I can't install 3rd party extensions :(

Comment: @user990463 ah I see. That does make it more laborious, but it is definitely necessary if you want to create a robust application (just think about HTML tags within attribute-strings or HTML comments ... any regex solution will badly choke on those; not even speaking of invalid HTML which can usually be partially handled by DOM parsers)

Comment: Yes I agree with that, regex is not really suitable for complex HTML replacement thought. So I'll get into PHP DOM Parsing ;) Thanks for advice bro!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

You can create a callback function that applies the html_entity_decode functionality on your match.